# Is there a way to get value of constructor parameter at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, reflection.emit

What I'm trying to do is copy existing `attributes` from one `property` to another.
Here is my code for now:

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(Example).GetProperties())
{
            FieldBuilder field = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + prop.Name, prop.PropertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder =
                typeBuilder.DefineProperty(prop.Name,
                                 PropertyAttributes.HasDefault,
                                 prop.PropertyType,
                                 null);

            object[] attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (var attr in attributes)
            {
                //Here I need to get value of constructor parameter passed in declaration of Example class
                ConstructorInfo attributeConstructorInfo = attr.GetType().GetConstructor(new Type[]{});
                CustomAttributeBuilder customAttributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(attributeConstructorInfo,new Type[]{});
                propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(customAttributeBuilder);
            }
}
```

It's working but only for `attributes` which have parameterless `constructor`.
For e.g. "DataTypeAttribute" have only `constructors` with `parameter`.

Now I wondering if there is a way to get current value of `attribute` `constructor`

Let's say I have this model:

```
public class Example
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public virtual string Desc { get; set; }
    public virtual string StartDt { get; set; }

    public Example()
    {

    }
}
```

For now I'm able to `copy` only `RequiredAttribute` because it has parameterless `constructor`. I'm unable to `copy` `DataTypeAttribute`. So I would like to get this `value` `DataType.Text` from my example model.

Anyone have some ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `GetCustomAttributes()`, which returns constructed attributes, use [`GetCustomAttributesData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributesdata.aspx). It returns a collection of `CustomAttributeData`, which contains exactly what you need: the constructor used to create the attribute, its arguments and also information about named arguments of the attribute.

Comment: NOTE: when there is only parameterless constructor GetCustomAttributeData() returns 1 AttributeData

Comment: @harry180 Isn't that exactly what it should return?

Comment: could you explain why it should `return` `AttributeTarget` in case of parameterless `constructor`it's weird for me. I thought that it will `return` `null` or empty `array`.

Comment: @harry180 I don't understand what are you trying to say. What does `AttributeTargets` (is that what you meant?) have to do with anything? If a member has one attribute created using parameterless constructor, then `GetCustomAttributeData()` will return a single `CustomAttributeData` whose `ConstructorArguments` will be empty.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is when you get parameterless constructor `GetCustomAttributeData()` return always 1 element(which can confuse a lot)